sqlsrv drivers in php8.2 not loading in
i have a php problem. i need to install the sqlsrv drivers. i did that. i added them in the ext folder (i am using xampp and had to create it myself). see image of finder window.

then i added the extension in the php.ini. see image of the ide.
but then i noticed that extension_dir was commented out with the ;. so i uncommented it and added the path to it (i know on the image it is /ext but now it is the absolute path)
that seems to do something, since security blocks the two files, then i allowed acces to it. after that i tried restarting the apache server but it was still not appearing in the phpinfo() list

then i did phpinfo() in the php, but that did not show the drivers there.
i searched and tried some things. but i just cant get it to work.
i would really appreciate any help
i am using xampp with php 8.2 on the latest macos version
